# How to explain the colour of these scots pines?

Tags: botany, species-identification, plant-anatomy

I would like to know why the trunks of scots pines have a particular colour, at least in Estonia, as shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Meenikunno_maastikukaiteala.jpg).

[image: Scots pine (Pinus sylvestris)]

The bottom part of the trunks is darker than the upper part. What could explain this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Let me know if I can improve my question, add relevant tags, and so on. I'm new on this SE site, so I may not ask suitable questions…

Comment: Looks like they've lost a good deal of their bark on the upper trunks. Could be a result of a severe weather event, but more likely it's some sort of disease or insect infestation.

Comment: Or maybe that's just the way it looks in the wild. I'm from the northeastern US, and we generally only see Scotch pine on Christmas tree farms, where they are tended to grow well, but don't grow that high, for obvious reasons. If you *do* see them in the wild, they're often stunted and twisted, as they're not adapted to our soil that well. I've also heard from tree farmers that they're susceptible to some fungal or insect infestation (I don't remember which) that can kill them pretty quickly, so you have to keep a close eye on them and treat them with various chemicals to keep them healthy.

Comment: Could be squirrels...

Comment: This seems *not* a species-identification question. Rather it seems a plant-anatomy (bark) question.

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's intrinsic, not extrinsic causes (i.e. not squirrels etc. just something that the tree does) because the pattern is observed so ubiquitously across the species and its range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bark of some *pinus* species, like *pinus sylvestris* and *pinus pinaster* naturally turns orange when they are a bit older. Other species stay grayisch black, like *pinus nigra* (hence the name).

By the way: I have never seen *pinus sylvestris* grow so straight. Is it possible this is another species, for example P. pinaster?

Sources: Den nya nordiska floran (Mossberg&Stenberg 2003) and Heukels' flora van Nederland (van der Meijden 2005).

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question - the question asks why the pattern is present, you've simply stated that some species do this. I also think the original species ID is correct, they often grow straight, especially in managed forests.

Comment: @rg255 It depends if you think the question aks for a fysiological explanation or that the question (and some responses) seem to assume the colour is caused by some external factor. I think it asks for the latter, in which case my answer is valid. And from your comment i see we agree on the intrinsic nature of the colour.